# How to use MFA in playwright?

Tags: javascript, authentication, playwright, multi-factor-authentication

I tried using Persistent context approach from playwright website but its not working
From the [multi-factor-authentication docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#multi-factor-authentication)

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const userDataDir = '/path/to/directory';
const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir
                                        , { headless: false });
// Execute login steps manually in the browser window
```

I used this code

```
describe("Learn Playwright", () => {
  test('basic test', async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch(
       { args: ['--disable-web-security',]
        ,headless: false
       });

    const userDataDir = 'user/data/dir';
    const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir
                        , { headless: false });
    // Create a new page inside context.
    const page = await context.newPage();
    context.close
    })
});
```

but the file is not getting updated inside dir directory. If anyone can elaborate what is wrong here? It will be really helpful.

Comment: As described in https://playwright.dev/docs/auth/#lifecycle after creating new page with `context.newPage()` you should login to the web site manually in the page. Once you close the browser its profile will be persisted in `userDataDir`. Does `'user/data/dir'` exist?

Comment: I try to figure this out as well, see [playwright/issues/14312](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14312)